# Using entity framework, LINQ expression returns null values for columns that are populated in the DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am attempting to build an ASP.NET MVC 4 web app, which is similar to a very basic e-mail system, using Entity Framework's code first approach. To demonstrate the problem I am having, consider the following C# classes.

```
public class Message
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User From { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User To { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public bool IsTrash { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpam { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

After seeding the database, the first message column appears like so:

```
Id  Subject Content CreatedAt   IsRead  IsTrash IsSpam  From_Id To_Id
1   Howdy   Lorem   2012-02-10  0       0       0       2       1
```

And two users, with the IDs listed above, exist in the Users table.

If I run the following LINQ, it shows that both From and To for that message are null but all other fields are correctly populated:

```
dbContext.Messages.Single(o=>o.Id==1);
```

What am I doing wrong that would lead to those two fields being null? Is it possibly a flaw in the organization of my classes?

Comment: dtryon is correct. You are missing virtual keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that From and To belong to are complex type and you should declare them as `virtual` so that they can be loaded correctly.